# Wird »abgewandt« in diesem Zitat als Adjektiv oder als Partizip II des Verbs »abwenden« benutzt?

Tags: adverb, past-participle

> »Und die kleine Antonie [...], den hübschen Blondkopf ein wenig vom Gesichte des Großvaters abgewandt, blickte [...]« (Thomas Manns *Buddenbrooks*)

Warum ist dieser Satz nicht so formuliert?

> »Und die kleine Antonie [...], **die ihren** hübschen Blondkopf ein wenig vom Gesichte des Großvaters **abgewandt hatte**, blickte [...]«

Comment: Es ist ein Partizip. *Und die kleine Antonie [...], **(hatte)** den hübschen Blondkopf ein wenig vom Gesichte des Großvaters abgewandt, blickte [...]

Comment: Aber warum gibt es keinen »hatte« im Roman? Und dann warum klingt diesen Satz nicht wie: »Und die kleine Antonie [...], die ihren hübschen Blondkopf ein wenig vom Gesichte des Großvaters abgewandt hatte, blickte [...]«?

Comment: Writers can choose from various ways of saying things, and one thing they take into account is the rhythm of the sentence. Thomas Mann left  "die" and "hätte" out predominantly in order to get a better rhythm here, I would say.

Comment: In German, stray participles function as a static description of the scene. With *hatte*, there is more focus on the action of *abwenden*.

Comment: Danke. Vielleicht haben Sie Recht. Aber es ist auch grammatikalisch korrekt?

Comment: Ja. Es ist sogar eine gängige Konstruktion, selbst in gesprochenem Deutsch. *Ich stelle mir eine Stadt vor allem zugeparkt und verdreckt vor. Das Geschrei schon hörend habe ich mich schnell wieder verdrückt. Das ist mir alles einerlei, gehupft wie gesprungen.* (gehupft: Variante von "gehüpft")

Comment: @user26328: Der Roman wurde 1901 veröffentlicht, es handelt sich also um Deutsch, das mehr als 100 Jahre alt ist. Damals (und auch davor) war es generell üblich, in solchen Konstruktionen das Hilfsverb wegzulassen. Das hat nicht nur Mann gemacht, sondern so gut wie alle Autoren dieser Zeit. In einem Text aus dem 21. Jahrhundert würde man das als Fehler ansehen, bei alten Texten ist das aber korrekt.

Answer (score 3):

Deine Beispiele haben jeweils 3 Teile:

> **(1)** Und die kleine Antonie [...]
>
> **(2a)** den hübschen Blondkopf ein wenig vom Gesichte des Großvaters abgewandt
>
> **(2b)** **die** ihren hübschen Blondkopf ein wenig vom Gesichte des Großvaters abgewandt **hatte**
>
> **(3)** blickte [...]

Dass es sich bei (2a) um eine [Partizipialkonstruktion](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partizip#Bildung_des_Partizip_II) handelt, wurde bereits gesagt.

Warum hat sich Thomas Mann hierfür entschieden?

Neben den in den Kommentaren vorgebrachten Erwägungen mag Folgendes eine Rolle spielen:

»*die*« und »*hatte*« sind für das Verständnis des Mittelteils nicht erforderlich, darum kann darauf verzichtet werden.

Zum anderen musst du als Leser – kommst du bei Teil (3) an – Teil (1) noch im Kopf haben, was umso leichter fällt, je kürzer Teil (2) ist (und je kürzer Teil (1) ist). Denn dieses *»blickte«* bezieht sich auf Teil (1). Durch das Aussparen wird die gesamte Konstruktion einfacher, der Leser hat weniger Mühe.

Comment: Danke. Sehr klar.

Answer (score 2):

Es ist ein Partizip. Die grammatische Konstruktion heißt [Partizipialsatz](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Form/Partizip.html). Sie ist genauso mit einem Partizip I möglich, und es gibt sie auch in vielen anderen Sprachen (Englisch, Lateinisch, ...)